# HttpURLConnection Get 500 error instead of 401 error

Tags: java, ajax, spring, postman, httpurlconnection

When i call a API from postman when i get 401 (accepted code) from postman, but i get 500 from my spring  project.

My HttpURLConnection  configuration is :

HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

```
        con.setRequestMethod("GET");
        con.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Bearer " + token_);
        con.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.5");
        con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");
        con.addRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:221.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/31.0"); 
        con.setDoOutput(true);
        con.setDoInput(true);
        int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
```

Comment: Check the server-side log files for exceptions.

Comment: thanks @StephenC actually i call a API which is not develop by me and i can not access server side easily.

Comment: OK so your code is saying "I am going to send some input to the server" in a GET request.  Is that intentional?  Are you actually sending anything?  Note that when you call `getResponseCode` that will commit the request and wait until the response arrives.